# How to share file with User with just read privileges

Tags: permissions, file-sharing

There is one user Lets call him B and he needs access Just to Read the File MEANS READ ACCESS and that file is own by another user A .

How can I grant access to user A's file to User B.

Comment: Are you using Samba?

Comment: No dear its just fresh system. Nothing installed Yet.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on A's group and B's group. If they are in the same, you need to check group permission (middle of the permission line) are enabling reading :

```
-rw-r--r--
```

Here, user can read and write, group can only read, and other can only read.

If A and B are not in the same group, then B have the *other* permissions, and you need to set those to read.

Reminder: to change a file permission, open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type

```
chmod g+r myFile
```

`g` means group, but it can be `u` for user or `o` for other.
`r`means read, and it could be replace by `w`for write or `x` to execute.

Comment: Thnx for info. Tell me should i set it on User level or Group level  ??because both are in different group. 2:Can root user do this if owner of user is not available if Yes then HOW. 3:And when this is done how to access the file. Sorry for troubling u as this is my first time with FILE SHARING THING IN LINUX

Comment: 1. If it's A's file, _user_ only impact A. If they are in different groups, you should set _other_ permissions: `chmod o+r myFile`.
2. Yes, you can change permission with root user, just `sudo` the command.
3. Once you can read it, you can open it with any application. I recommend `cat` or `vim`. Let me know if it worked !

Comment: Ok i have set the privilege of A's file to Read by using chmod o+r using ROOT account. Now how to access this file using User B

Comment: by passing the command **ls /home/mra/Desktop/new file** It gave me following output  ***-rw----r-- 1 mra mra 26 Noc TIME /home/mra/Desktop/newfile***  Now advice me how to access this file from User B's account . Thanx man

Comment: Just log in with B's session, or use `su B` to substitute B's identity in a terminal and open the file like `cat /home/mra/Desktop/newfile`. You should see the content of your file displayed in the terminal.

Comment: Yes dear i did exactly but it gave me Permission Denied error